# What are the key differences from the LOKI project which was a fork of monero?

Tags: monero-forks, cryptocurrency-comparison, loki

The LOKI project was a fork of Monero. What did they change that makes it different from Monero?

Comment: You can read the changes in their whitepaper here https://loki.network/whitepaper, but i don't think this question is very pertinent to ask in the Monero stack exchange you should go ask in their channels

Comment: For better or worse, this site does allow for other cryptonote/fork questions. See https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23731/are-questions-about-other-cryptonote-coins-on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loki fork main differences are:

- Developed by a public development team vs monero's anonymous developers. However there are a few loki devs that are anonymous. The only public monero dev that is also on the loki team is Tom Winget.
- Its a hybrid POW and POS mining model vs monero is just POW.
- Has adopted monero random x mining algo.
- More focus on private communications like the loki messenger and mixnet than vs monero's target as being money.

Comment: "Has adopted monero random x mining algo. " doesn't seem like a difference then ?